# Typescript discriminated unions for tuples not working as expected

Tags: typescript, tuples, typescript-typings, discriminated-union

I'm trying to write a type that I can re-use in a lot of my code, where the functions would return a tuple in the following form:

If an error occurred in the function the tuple would have an Error object as the first element, and `null` as the second element, while if the function was "successful", the tuple it returns would have a `null` as at the first position and the data it returns in the second position.

This is somewhat similar to the nodejs callback style, where the callback gets an error object as a first parameter (if there was an error), and the data in the second parameter (if it was successful).
Now the way I'd type this looks like this:

```js
type SuccessResponse<T> = [null, T];
type ErrorResponse<E = Error> = [E, null]
type Response<T, E = Error> = SuccessResponse<T> | ErrorResponse<E>;
```

So in this version every function would return a `Response` and set it's own type in the generic T. My issue is that it seems that Typescript is merging the two tuples in a weird way (at least for me).

A very contrived example:

```js
interface User {
  name: string
};


async function getUser(userId: string): Response<User> {
  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findById(userId);
    if (!user) {
      return [new Error('No user found'), null];
    }
    return [null, user];
  } catch (error) {
    return [error, null];
  }
}

;(async () => {
  const [err, user] = await getUser('1');

  if (err) {
    err.message; // This works
    return;
  }
    
  console.log(user.name); // TS: Object is possibly 'null'.(2531)
  
})();
```

Am I typing something wrong here? It seems to me that Typescript should be able to know that after the `if` clause the `user` should be of type `User` and not `User | null`.

Please note that I know that I could use type guard for this, but I would loose the beauty of having the response already be destructured. The code then would look something like this:

```js
function isErrorResponse(response: Response<any>): response is ErrorResponse {
  return !!response[0];
}

;(async () => {
  const response = await getUser('1');

  if (isErrorResponse(response)) {
    const [err] = response; // I need to destructure here
    err.message; // This still works
    return
  }
  const [, user] = response; // Another destructure
  console.log(user.name); // Now this works too
  
})();
```

Comment: sorry you're right, updated the description (originally I wrote the code with an else clause but switched to early returns and failed to update the description)

Comment: I think it does if the lesson is that this type of thing is basically impossible in Typescript right now. Although as a user I feel like this should actually work as expected.
For example the compiler still stops you if you try to do this inside the `getUser` function: `return [null, null]`.

Comment: The answer is that you get the desired behaviour if you don't destructure the tuple, because in that case your `if` condition will narrow the tuple's type.